# How can I copy-paste files into a WSL podman container?

Tags: wordpress, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-machine, wsl-2, podman

I spun up a wordpress and mysql container inside podman to test a plugin. I need to copy the wordpress `/uploads/` folder  inside the new instance. I thought that would be the easiest part, but I soon found out that just copy pasting it wouldn't work - `You need permission to perform this action.` windows explorer error.

Next I tried using `podman cp` command. Speciffically:

```
podman cp :D:/xxx/WP/demo/uploads/ containerID:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

but got `error rewriting "D:\\xxx\\WP\\demo\\uploads" to be relative to "/": expected root directory to be an absolute path, got "/"` error that I didn't figure out how to solve (I tried providing the path in different styles but nothing worked out).

Than I  tried to copy it using `wsl -d podman-machine-default` running:

```
[user@user /]$ cp -r /mnt/d/xxx/WP/demo/uploads /home/user/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/wp_test_env_wordpress/_data/wp-content/uploads/
```

but i got a  `cannot create directory... permission denied` error, even though the exact path already  exists.

I tried each of them a bunch of times  but still didn't manage to get any to work.

What is the easiest way I could copy over a file from Windows FS into a podman container?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found to work was to cd directly into `[user@user wp-content]$`(`wsl -d podman-machine-default`) and to run `sudo cp -r /mnt/d/xxx/WP/demo/uploads/ ./`.

I am still not sure why using the whole path didn't work and would love to know if an easier solution exists (enabling copy and paste directly between windows and WSL maybe).